# Javascript no se actualiza al instante en mi pagina web

Tags: javascript, java-ee

Les explico, tengo una página web que tiene un menú en la barra izquierda, este menú tiene varios `li` y `ul` , estos elementos deberían estar escondidos dependiendo de una variable que le concede permiso a los usuarios, por ejemplo:

```
Usuario 1: [1,2,3,4] <-- Es decir puede visualizar los li con los id : 1,2,3 y 4

Usuario 1: [1,2] <-- Es decir puede visualizar los li con los id : 1 y 2
```

El sistema tiene un `login` y dependiendo del usuario que entre tiene ciertos permisos, funciona casi perfecto excepto que cuando cierro sesión con el usuario 1 y entro con el usuario 2 se visualiza el menú como si fuera el usuario 1 **(es decir con las opciones 1,2,3,4)**, esto se arregla con un `F5` **actualizando la pagina**, pero queda mal que siempre que inicie sesión con otro usuario deba actualizar la pagina para que el menú se vea correctamente.

¿Acaso las variables de `JavaScript` se quedan guardadas en cache o el menú se quedan almacenados en cache y por eso debo actualizar la página para que se vea correctamente?

Acá adjunto imágenes

**Usuario con varios privilegios**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí cerré sesión y entre con otro usuario con menos privilegios, aún así el menú se muestra como el usuario anterior:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego de hacer `F5` y actualizar la pagina ya se muestra como debería, de aquí en adelante funciona bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como les decía el único problema es que al iniciar sesión con otro usuario el menú no se actualiza, me obliga  a actualizar la página.

Aquí el orden de como están los `scripts`:

`Script` para traer el menú de otra página

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#menu").load("menu.jsp"); 
});
</script>
```

`Script` para ocultar los `li` y `ul` dependiendo de los permisos del usuario

```
<script>
function permisosMenu() {
      var cadena = <%=permisos%>
      if(!cadena.includes(1) && !cadena.includes(2) && !cadena.includes(3) && !cadena.includes(4) && !cadena.includes(26))
        document.getElementById("bloque1").style.display ="none";

      if(!cadena.includes(5) && !cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) &&
          !cadena.includes(9) && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12) &&
          !cadena.includes(13) && !cadena.includes(14) && !cadena.includes(15) && !cadena.includes(16) && 
          !cadena.includes(27) && !cadena.includes(28))
        document.getElementById("bloque2").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(6) && !cadena.includes(7) && !cadena.includes(8) && !cadena.includes(9) 
          && !cadena.includes(10) && !cadena.includes(11) && !cadena.includes(12) && !cadena.includes(27) &&
          !cadena.includes(28))
        document.getElementById("bloque2_op2").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(17) && !cadena.includes(18) && !cadena.includes(19) && !cadena.includes(20) )
        document.getElementById("bloque3").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(21) && !cadena.includes(22) && !cadena.includes(23))
        document.getElementById("bloque4").style.display ="none";

  if(!cadena.includes(24) && !cadena.includes(25))
        document.getElementById("bloque5").style.display ="none";

  for (var i = 1; i <= 32; i++) {
      if(!cadena.includes(i)){
        //alert("op"+i);
        document.getElementById("op"+i).style.display ="none";
    }
}


}
</script>
```

Este último **script** `permisosMenu()` se ejecuta en un `onload` en el `body`.

Los `scripts` funcionan a la perfección fuera de ese detalle, creo que es tal vez el orden como los ejecuto o de algún modo se queda almacenado en caché.

Comment: porque no despues de finalizar session ejecutas la funcion , con eso se solucionaria...creo

Comment: como me serviría ejecutar la función al cerrar sesión ? de que me serviría eso?

Comment: limpiaria el menu antes de volverte a loguear, de hecho lo puedes hacer al cargar la pagina de login

Comment: debes crear otra función que te actualice